# Calculating a normalized average with Rails using Postgres JSON column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have a large stats table in a Postgres DB where the schema looks like this:

```
player_id: integer,
region: string,
position: string,
league: string,
stats: json
```

I used [this blog post](http://robertbeene.com/rails-4-2-and-postgresql-9-4/) to build the following query to find the average of a given attribute in the stats json object (using as an example the 'hits' stat):

```
attributes = {region: 'x', position: 'y', league: 'z'}
Stat.where(attributes).average("cast(payload ->> 'hits' as integer)").to_f
```

That works well and it's fast.  Some of the stats, however, need to be built as a function of time the player was in game.  Given a stats object with the following format:

```
{
  "kills":10
  "time_played":120 # seconds
}
```

I would want to get a value of 5 kills per minute (`10 / (120/60)`) assuming that was the only stat found (it would be much more, that's why I'm doing `average`, but for the sake of a simple example...)

Here I'm quite stuck.  I know that sql has no trouble dividing things, but throwing in the JSON has me confused.  I've tried this:

```
Stat.where(attributes).average("cast(payload ->> 'kills' as integer) / (cast(payload ->> 'time_played' as integer) / 60)").to_f
```

it returns `0` - and I'm not really sure how to debug this statement.  Any ideas?

**solution**:

this is what ended up working, with help from EgonWilzer:

```
def query_for(stat, per_minute: false)
  base = "cast(payload ->> '#{stat}' as float)"

  return base unless per_minute
  base + " / (cast(payload ->> 'time_played' as float) / 60)"
end
```

Comment: The problem is probably the division integer / integer, which will always return 0 if the second one is bigger. Maybe you could try it with `as real` instead of `as integer`?

Comment: nice idea, @EgonWilzer, but doesn't change output.

Comment: i take it back - i had a mistake (wasn't dividing the `time_played` bit by 60!) and that does seem to work - if you add it as an answer i'll happily accept it.  cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the division integer / integer, which will always return 0 if the second one is bigger.

You could probably get the expected result with `as real` instead of `as integer`.